# Mercurial: get fresh copy

Tags: mercurial

I have a local repository and I want to get the latest changes from a remote repository. I know i can clone but clone only works on new directories. I know i can delete the local repository and then clone but i want to know how do it the Mercurial way if there is one.

EDIT: hg pull -u doesn't work if there are conflicts. I don't want to resolve conflicts I just want to get a fresh copy of the remote repo regardless of local changes.

ANSWER: Short answer: Maybe it can be done (see answer below) but re-clone is easier.

Long answer: if you want to get the latest from a remote and disregard your local changes and commits then you'll have to clone to a new local repository or remove the local repository and clone another one. This is because if you have conflicting changes then hg will force you to resolve them manually.

Which is OK but I just wanted to know if it can be done without removing my local repo.

Comment: You definitely need to read http://hginit.com/

Comment: I read the documentation for 2 hours before deciding to post the question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `hg strip`, which isn't part of the Mercurial core.  It's available through the MqExtension.  You can enable it by adding the following in your .hgrc or Mercurial.ini file (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension)

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

Then you will be able to:

```
hg strip rev
```

This will remove your changesets to the point where you shouldn't have any merge conflicts.  This will impact the branch history though.  But then again, that's not so bad, if you keep them any good future changeset will have an ancestor that you decided to trash.

If you are just trying something out, you're better of doing it in a separate branch which is easy to close and abandon later.

If you really are looking to keep the bad changeset you can pass in configuration option to the merge command like this

```
hg --config ui.merge=internal:other merge
```

This is documented in [Mercurial tips and tricks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge).

Comment: I want to hit the remote repo but i just want to override my local copy. what you suggested doesn't work because if you have a conflict you'll end up with 2 heads and still have to merge

Comment: I wanted to try strip but it seems that I have to install an extension. At this point i think re-cloning is easier and i'm fine with it. I'm marking yours as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, it's easy enough though, I'll edit my answer to mention the extension and setup.  Can't do it in the comments as it will loose it's formatting.

Comment: The --config way shouldn't require any extension.  Have you given that one a try? I can't say I tried and would like to know the results.

Comment: had same problem, hg clone is very slow for big projects - hg strip worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you're just looking for this:

```
hg pull
hg up --clean
```

That will pull latest set of revisions from the remote repoistory and then update your local repository with a clean copy, regardless of whether or not you have made any changes to the files. No merging necessary.

The only caveat is, if you have added files to your local repository, and they have not been committed, they will be orphaned (left in place, but not in the repository) after the update. If you do an `hg stat` you should see them denoted with question marks. If the added files have been committed to your local repository, Mercurial will properly clean up after them.

Here's the remote repository (remote rev 6):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         3/24/2011   2:16 PM            .hg
-a---         3/24/2011   2:16 PM         83 addedtoremote.txt
-a---         3/24/2011   1:56 PM        726 sample.txt
```

Here's the local repository (cloned from remote rev 4 earlier) with changed and added files (local rev 5):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         3/24/2011   2:03 PM            .hg
-a---         3/24/2011   2:05 PM          9 sample.txt
-a---         3/24/2011   2:05 PM         58 addedtolocal.txt
```

Here's the local repository after doing a pull and clean update (local rev 6):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         3/24/2011   2:17 PM            .hg
-a---         3/24/2011   2:17 PM         83 addedtoremote.txt
-a---         3/24/2011   2:15 PM        726 sample.txt
```

The changes to `sample.txt` have been wiped out, `addedtolocal.txt` has been deleted and `addedtoremote.txt` has been added.

Comment: I does not work if there are conflicts between the 2 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just "pull" changes from the remote repo. Think that "pull" and "push" are change-sets transactions between repos.

Once done, you have to "update" the sources.

Comment: hg pull -u doesn't work if there are conflicts. I don't want to resolve conflicts I just want to get a fresh copy from the remote repo.

Comment: hg pull will make you get the changes from the repo, without updating your current code. When you'll be ready to deal with the conflict, you'll have to "merge". I let you read the documentations to uderstand how to do it.

Comment: If you want to blow away your own changes, first issue a `hg revert --all`, then do `hg pull -u` and `hg update` (or `hg fetch` if you have that enabled.)

Comment: I belive hg revert -all won't work either because I have committed changes to the local repo and revert only removes uncommitted changes.

Comment: @Klaim: Thanks for the RTFM! really nice of you.

Comment: well i've been reading for 30 min and don't seem to be able to find how to do merge without resolving conflicts manually. All the links advice to use a diff tool to resolve conflicts manually BUT I DON"T WANT TO RESOLVE CONFLICTS. see for yourself: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html and http://hginit.com/04.html

Comment: @Delucia: I've answered to you, I just point you to the manual for DETAILS. The thing is it's not easy to fully answer such a basic question : git and mercurial are all about push/pull and update. If you read basic tutorials, you should be able to answer to your own question.
If you want to resolve conflict, then you have no other choice than to remove your own changes. There is an option to "update" that does this but I don't remember witch one (I'm not using it right now)

Comment: @Klaim: sorry i thought i got RTFMed. it seems that there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase your modifications, minimizing the need for merges. Just call  `hg pull --rebase`

You'll have to have `rebase` extension enabled in your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```

Comment: hg pull --rebase also requires you to resolve conflicts manually. I tried it and it launched the diff tool.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is such a common action, there is an extension that does a `hg pull -u`, `hg merge` and `hg commit` in one command:

[`hg fetch`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FetchExtension)

From the [hg book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html#sec:tour-merge:fetch):

> Enabling the fetch extension is easy.
>   Edit the `.hgrc` file in your home
>   directory, and either go to the
>   extensions section or create an
>   extensions section. Then add a line
>   that simply reads “fetch=”.
>
> ```
> [extensions]
> fetch =
> ```

Comment: Yes, thanks. The `-u` actually does an update. I updated my answer to clarify.